# what are the coordinates of Berkeley DB JE 5.0.x in Maven Central?

Tags: java, maven, berkeley-db, berkeley-db-je

What are the coordinates of [Berkeley DB JE 5.0.x](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/berkeleydb/downloads/index-098622.html) in Maven Central (or some other repo maybe)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The link given by [Shaun Hare](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10095243/959118) (Oracle's bdb [download page](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/berkeleydb/downloads/maven-087630.html)) now holds an example Maven configuration accessing Oracle's Maven repo.

Following that example I included the bdb je by adding Oracle's repository directly. If you're using a repository manager such as Nexus, you might include the repository there instead:

```
<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>com.sleepycat</groupId>
    <artifactId>je</artifactId>
    <version>5.0.58</version>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>

<repositories>
  <repository>
    <id>oracleReleases</id>
    <name>Oracle Released Java Packages</name>
    <url>http://download.oracle.com/maven</url>
    <releases>
      <enabled>true</enabled>
    </releases>
    <snapshots />
  </repository>
</repositories>
```

Edit: Repaired broken hyperlinks

Comment: this appears to be broken. that url gives a 404.

Comment: Pasting the link in the browser fails, but the repository works. Using the code in a Maven project downloads the dependencies just fine (as I just re-checked:-).

Comment: According to a thread on the oracle forums, there is no browsing allowed of the repository. https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?messageID=10283105&#10283105

Answer (score 1):

See here http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/berkeleydb/downloads/maven-087630.html

so http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sleepycat/je/4.0.92

Edit sorry wrong version I suggest

```
wget http://download.oracle.com/maven/com/sleepycat/je/5.0.34/je-5.0.34{.jar,.jar.md5,.jar.sha1,.pom,.pom.md5,.pom.sha1,-sources.jar,-sources.jar.md5,-sources.jar.sha1,-javadoc.jar,-javadoc.jar.md5,-javadoc.jar.sha1}
```

and upload to own repo

o

Comment: What about 5.0.x, as I asked above?

Comment: So the answer is - "it's not available in any public repositories". Am I right?